# MySQL using column values in query

Tags: mysql

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| animal_name | tag_name | tag_group |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| CatBlue     | cat      | species   |
| CatBlue     | blue     | colour    |
| DogBlue     | dog      | species   |
| DogBlue     | blue     | colour    |
| DogRed      | dog      | species   |
| DogRed      | red      | colour    |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

Table above is a simplified view of various joined tables.

It's part of a system that returns results based on tags selected. Problem is if blue and cat tags are selected, the system currently returns DogBlue as well. (It's using OR in the SQL)

In MySQL, how do I search only for animals that have one or more tags from all tag groups? Is it possible to use the tag_group column values in a query?

EDIT:
I want to be able to request table rows where the animal has the colour **blue** and species **cat**. WHERE tag_name = cat OR tag_name = blue brings up the dog as well.

Comment: Provide table structure(s) with example data as formatted data not images.. And provide expected output as formatted text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To to get the `animal_name` who have all these properties you can use conditional aggregation like

```
SELECT animal_name
FROM table1
GROUP BY animal_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'cat' AND tag_group = 'species' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'blue' AND tag_group = 'colour' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
;
```

Using Mysql you could also use `sum(a=b)`, `SUM(tag_name = 'blue' AND tag_group = 'colour')` as shorthand, using expression inside `sum()` will result you a boolean value 0/1, true/false

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e941/1)

[For *Blue dog*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e941/6)

```
SELECT animal_name
FROM table1
GROUP BY animal_name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'dog' AND tag_group = 'species' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
AND SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'blue' AND tag_group = 'colour' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
;
```

As per last comment *I need both the blue cat and the blue dog*
Add `OR` criteria to have both animal names

```
SELECT animal_name
FROM table1
GROUP BY animal_name
HAVING (
  SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'dog' AND tag_group = 'species' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
  AND 
  SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'blue' AND tag_group = 'colour' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
) OR (
  SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'cat' AND tag_group = 'species' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
  AND
  SUM(CASE WHEN tag_name = 'blue' AND tag_group = 'colour' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0
)
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/CFBRH89477)

Comment: Hi, How would I add blue dogs to the request? I played around with your demo but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: Thanks, but for my example I need both the blue cat and the blue dog. In the real application there's a lot of entries but I want to keep things simple so I can learn how to do this.

Comment: @xgarb i have updated my answer as per your last comment

Comment: Great.. it's working. My application actually uses Doctrine but I wanted to try and understand it in MySQL first. I'm using it something like this in my code (looping through an array of grouped tags):

`$queryBuilder->andHaving("SUM(CASE WHEN tt.name IN ('".$inString."') AND tg.group_name = '".$key."' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  ) > 0");`

Thanks for your help. I never would have been able to work this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subrequest with your conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT animal_name, sum(tag_name = 'blue' OR tag_name = 'cat') as sum_condition
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY animal_name
HAVING sum_condition = 2) datas USING(animal_name)
```

EDIT to reply at the comment

```
SELECT * FROM Table 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT animal_name, sum(tag_name = 'blue' OR (tag_name IN ('cat','dog'))) as sum_condition
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY animal_name
HAVING sum_condition = 2) datas USING(animal_name)
```

EDIT : My bad i had forgotten a parenthesis
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9e941/15/0

Comment: Hi, How would I add blue dogs to the request?